# cannot include css files from node_modules on webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, mern

I am trying to include some modules that require their own css files in my server render react project and i cant seem to get it to work. FYI that modules are react-material-grid and react-toolbox

I am using https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter as my project and i am trying to put react toolbox while i am getting an error when trying to run that i cannot properly read a css from that module. You can see the configs of the webpack inside on that project or below

**React-toolbox installation** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toolbox

**error i am getting**

```
/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/theme.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :root {
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

**babel webpack config**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/master/webpack.config.babel.js

**dev**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/master/webpack.config.dev.js

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you get it? I run 'npm run start' and it is ok

Comment: you downloaded the mern project and added the react-toolbox and worked? Try put a component on a page

Comment: add react-toolbox? How can i do this? You did not describe what you did. I just downloaded mern and run it

Comment: "I am using https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter as my project and i am trying to put react toolbox while i am getting an error when trying to run that i cannot properly read a css from that module. You can see the configs of the webpack inside on that project or here"

Sorry if it wasnt clear. Quoting my question above. I am try on this project to run react-toolbox. If you try to include it you will see the error. It leads to a problem of misscofiguration of the webpack that i tried to fix with no luck.

Comment: Still no info about HOW you put react toolbox in mern

Comment: its a simple npm module that you can follow here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toolbox